# header.php background image looks different on different pages. Possible Browser Issue?

Tags: html, css

Okay, I have searched with no luck.  Not really even sure what is specifically wrong.

Here is what I can tell you.  I have included a header.php file on all my pages.  For the background I us a a texture image with css.

```
#header {background: #000 url('img/darkpattern.png') repeat;}
```

In the header file I use the same css file they are all the same, it works on the home page and another page, but in all the other pages it just looks solid black.  My first thought was that it was not locating the picture and just showing the #000, but I changed it to purple and it was still solid black.  When I purposely changed the file path it showed the purple.

Important note: This issue as described is only in Chrome. In safari it is solid black on all pages and in firefox it shows the pattern in all pages.  The Chrome issue is baffling.  All the styling is done in a css page and all pages link to the same header that links to the css page.  It seems to be changing my subtile pattern to a single color image.  Any idea what is happening and a way to fix it?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: how was this related to PHP?

Comment: I do not know if it specifically is, but you can clearly see where the php is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a height property might show the image. Of course, it would be great if you posted the HTML and all subsequent CSS in [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to see what exactly the issue is :)

Comment: jFiddle would not show this issue as it has to do with particular browsers and different pages.

Comment: agreed, but pasting code and then having someone help browser-test it would be a great step forward in helping you :)